# Matching dynamically drawn triangles and differentiating angles

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I am making a game wherein the user draws triangles on a grid and be congruent with other triangles.  However, the user gets additional points for having their new triangle in a different rotation from the original.  I would use the rotation property of the movieclip, but since the triangles are drawn into a dynamically created MC, they all have a rotation of 0 degrees.

Is there some way to do this?  I am absolutely stumped.

Comment: Without any kind of reference I don't think it is possible. Would it work if you add a base line by default, a line with a fixed starting point but an adjustable endpoint. They can move the endpoint around to adjust it to their needs, then complete the rest of the triangle.

Comment: The triangles are drawn by selecting points on a grid, so when the triangle is actually rendered, it is drawing lines at the same relative distances from the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.  What I did was have the program dig through the triangle to find the left-most and uppermost point. Then I draw all the triangles using this point as the origin.  This ensures that regardless of the order in which the dots are clicked, all triangles will have the same point of origin.

To detect whether they are matches, I wrote up a function that copies the triangles and moves them to the same point.  Because they now have the same origin point, they will occupy the same space if they are of the same angle.  Using this, I then wrote a function that checks to see if the triangles overlap completely.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a maths problem.

Firstly, if you have an equilateral triangle, you wouldn't reliably be able to work out the rotational difference since the sides are the same size.

Otherwise, you will always have 'the important side'

Assuming your triangle is isosceles, your important side is the one that is of a different length to the other two matching sides.

Assuming you have a scalene triangle, your most important side is the longest side.

Once you know your most important side...

You should be able to work out the important side of the users triangle using trig.

You should also know the important side of the base triangle the user is trying to draw against, since you are 'making' it.

Then you basically have two lines (the two important sides), use trig again to work out the difference in rotation between the two lines, then you are good to go.

Comment: That would work, but the triangles are nested inside a movieclip, and the lines themselves are not objects, so I cannot split them to measure